# Adding computer to an AD group via asp.net (c#) in a cross forest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Following problem: i'm trying to add a computer to an Active Directory group via ASP.NET & C# for a little rollout tool.

But as soon as i upload it on my server (IIS 8.5) the trouble starts. 
Everything like search for computers and groups works perfectly fine, but adding new computers to a group doesn't work

Here is my code for adding a computer to a group:

```
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destination_pc.Text))
        error_messages.Text = "Empty Field";
    else
    {
        PrincipalContext Domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.local");
        GroupPrincipal group;
        ComputerPrincipal MyComputer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Domain, destination_pc.Text);

        if (ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Domain, destination_pc.Text) != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < destination_packages.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Domain, destination_packages.Items[i].ToString());
                if (!MyComputer.IsMemberOf(group))
                {
                    group.Members.Add(Domain, IdentityType.Name, destination_pc.Text);
                    group.Save();
                }
            }
            destination_packages.Items.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            error_messages.Text = "Computer doesn't exist in AD";
        }

    }

}
```

This is giving us following error:

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is
>   denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 159:                    { Line 160:
>   group.Members.Add(Domain, IdentityType.Name, destination_pc.Text);
>   Line 161:                        group.Save(); Line 162:
>   } Line 163:                }
>
> Source File:  c:\Websites\ManageSoftware\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 
>   161
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. ]
>   System.DirectoryServices.Interop.IAds.SetInfo() +0
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges() +177
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UpdateGroupMembership(Principal
>   group, DirectoryEntry de, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes
>   authTypes) +1295
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal
>   p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership,
>   NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes) +175
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Update(Principal
>   p) +113    _Default.add_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Websites\ManageSoftware\Default.aspx.cs:161
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11750641
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +150    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +6016

So i thought through impersonation i could solve this, and tried many solutions like:

```
IIdentity WinId= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();
try
{
  // Access resources while impersonating.
  group.Save()
}
catch
{
  // Prevent exceptions propagating.
}
finally
{
  // Revert impersonation.
  wic.Undo();
}
```

or

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = 
    ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

group.Save();

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

But everything i try, i get following exception:

> Exception Details:
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations
>   error occurred.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 168:                     WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();
>   Line 169:                      Line 170:                      group.Save(); Line 171:                      Line
>   172:                      wic.Undo();
>
> Source File:  c:\Websites\ManageSoftware\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 
>   170
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error
>   occurred. ]    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail) +576673    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   +45    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +40    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +27
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   entry, String propertyName) +122
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String
>   propertyName) +162
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UpdateGroupMembership(Principal
>   group, DirectoryEntry de, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes
>   authTypes) +1089
>
> [PrincipalOperationException: An operations error occurred. ]
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UpdateGroupMembership(Principal
>   group, DirectoryEntry de, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes
>   authTypes) +1917
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal
>   p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership,
>   NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes) +175
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Update(Principal
>   p) +113    _Default.add_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Websites\ManageSoftware\Default.aspx.cs:170
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11750641
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +150    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +6016

my webconfig look like this at the moment:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="domainname.local\group1" />
      <allow roles="domainname.local\group2r" />
      <deny users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Changing the application pool identity to for example to Network Service, doesn't changed anything. 
Adding a account with enough permissions manually, isn't a solution because of security reasons.

Another Info: The IIS is in another forest than the Active Directory.

Thanks in advance